# Why is the output of word count not accurate when assigned to alias?

Tags: grep, alias, tcsh, word-count

I use `squeue` to display jobs like below

[image: jobs]

and I would like to count the number of running jobs (according to the fifth) column. The command

```bsh
squeue -h -u $USER | awk '{print $5}' | grep R | wc -l
```

does the job nicely so I put it into alias in `~/.cshrc` file as

```bsh
alias rj "squeue -h -u $USER | awk '{print $5}' | grep R | wc -l"
```

However, the alias never shows me the correct number. For example

[image: alias]

could you please help me on this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Because your whole command is inside double quotes, the inner `' '` don't act as quotes yet but only as regular text, and the `$5` is getting expanded as a *shell* variable right there during alias definition. It's probably an empty string, so your awk command becomes `awk '{print }'` which no longer cuts off unwanted columns, and as a result your grep command matches too much.

Backslash escape the `$`:

```
alias fj "... | awk '{print \$5}' | ..."
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to escape `$` but it is giving me `backslash not last character on line` error when I tried to run it. I then tried to escape `'` and `{}`, neither worked for me.

Comment: tcsh handling of quotes is different; need `"...{print"\$"5} ..."` (yuck)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to write a script for this, again, I am using `tcsh`. This is the script

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/tcsh
set n_running = `squeue -h -u $USER | awk '{print $5}' | grep R | wc -l`
set n_total = `squeue -h -u $USER | wc -l`
echo $n_running/$n_total
```

save it as `jn` and do `chmod +x jn`, then in `~/.cshrc` file you write

```bsh
alias jn '/path/to/jn'
```

and the path has to be absolute path. Then source `~/.cshrc` file and you are ready to use `jn`!

This script will print out number of running jobs over number of total jobs.

Comment: You don't need 4 different programs; more efficient and simpler `squeue -h -u $USER | awk -vs=/ '$5~/R/{++n} END{print +n s NR}'` . But as above quoting this into an alias is clumsy in tcsh.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 This is brilliant! I learned a lot from your code, but could you maybe explain what does `-vs=/` mean? I just could not find a reference to it. Also, it seems like in the print statement, having `+n` or `n` printed is equivalent, is that right?

Comment: `awk -vname=value` sets a variable, like `name=value` within the script; here it sets `s` to (the string containing) a slash character. I used this instead of a doublequoted string literal because I was (initially) hoping to do it in an alias and didn't want to have conflicting quotes. awk variables start out as the empty string if not explicitly initialized, which is treated as zero in arithmetic but not for printing; thus if there are no matches `print n` prints nothing but `print +n` prints `0` which is clearer and more consistent.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks a lot! This is very helpful!